# How to bind List<myclass> to scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a class myclass, which extends from Appointment. Now i have a scheduler and i set the Datasource of the schedulerStorage.Appoinments.Datasource to myclass. On runtime i create a List and set this as datasource. In my opinion the scheduler should get the myclass objects in the list as Appoinments. But the scheduler dont show anything. Cant find one single Appoinment.

Someone can tell me how to bind a objectlist to the scheduler in the right way? I think missunderstand something.

Test:

```
storage1.Appointments.DataSource = myListWithCustomAppointments;
storage1.RefreshData();
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(storage1.Appointments.Count));
```

the Test give me a number of 6 which is right. But the scheduler dont show the Appoinments.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed the mappings. You have to map some Properties of your class to the Properties of the Appointment class. Easiest way is if you extend from Appointment.